# How to log user in manually in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, oauth-2.0

Is it possible to log user in manually? My users don't have a password but only an oauth2 secure token. When matched with an external service, I want them to be logged in. How can I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

The `accounts-oauth` package can help you here. You may try `Accounts.oauth.credentialRequestCompleteHandle` method just like `accounts-facebook` package does:

https://github.com/meteor/accounts/tree/master/packages/accounts-facebook

The source of `Meteor.loginWithFacebook` is in `facebook.js`.

Comment: Thanks @aedm for your help. I, however ended up using my own logic with `Accounts.registerLoginHandler`